# Java ComboViewer react on edit, KeyListener?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, keylistener

I am using a JFace ComboViewer in my Plugin. As a convenience feature I'd like to change the current selection just by starting typing.
For that I added a KeyListener to the underlying Combo Element

What I get is an event as soon as I start typing, but unfortunately I do not get the changed value, but only the one before I started typing.

My keylistener, which has a reference tot he ComboViewer reacts currently in this way:

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          ISelection selection = combo.getSelection(); //combo is the ComboViewer

        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection && !selection.isEmpty()) {

            IStructuredSelection strucSel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

            node = (TreeNode) strucSel.getFirstElement();
...}
```

The first character I type actually makes it through the if-statement, any further typed character causes the selection to be empty.

So how do I get always a "current selection" and how can I obtain the changed value, it seems like reacting in the keylistener is to early, because the text-field I am typing in is not yet updated and thus will always provide old information?

Maybe I understood something wrong, but I could not imagine that I could be so hard getting an up-to-date information from a text field. 
Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ModifyListener` instead and query the current value of the combo's text box like this:

```
public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)
{
  String text = ((Combo) e.getSource()).getText();
  ...
}
```

But this will only give you the content of the text box. The combo viewer won't have - as far as I remember - any selection until you select an element from its drop down list or you programmatically set one using `setSelection(..)`. The visible text is basically only the label (as far the the combo viewer is concerned) and since labels don't have to be unique, it won't try to find the model element that belongs to the label. So I don't know what you expect the combo viewer's selection to be while someone is typing in the combo's text box. What kind of behaviour exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Won't a content assist be more helpfull? It works exactly like the content assist in Eclipse.